# PHP - how to cut off script early?

Tags: php

I have fairly simple PHP code, where it receives some information from a form. If there's an error, I want to print an error message, a link back, and cut off the rest of the script/page. How do I do this?

**Update**

Sorry I was unclear on this, but exit() was exactly what I wanted- it just printed an error message and ended the script. The page was only to verify the form, so it was fine if it quit early.

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Your question is very unclear .. you never just want to abort a script halfway, your page might come out mangled. If you're using Exceptions you'll be able to catch it at the top, that should be enough right?

Comment: Unclear what are you asking !

Comment: you could use die(); to end script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `exit()` or `die()` possibly.  This will make your PHP page stop in its tracks and I believe you can supply a message with it if you like.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `exit();` should do. You can also wrap your error message inside the `exit()` like so: `exit('My Error Message');`. More docs on the function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use `die()` to do that:

```
die("An error has occurred. <br> <a href='link_to_previous_page'>Go back</a>");
```

Comment: What if some HTML was already printed?

Comment: It'll print everything up to and including the message that was included in `die()`. I use this to my advantage when writing error pages because the page still has all the formatting I want, but it displays the error message instead of content.

Answer (score 1):

As kpsuperplane said, you can use `exit();` function, but you can use a `header('Location: url_of_the_error_or_help_page.php');` and then a `exit();` to redirect the user to whatever you want.